# Interesting results from LSTM RNN : lagged results for train and validation data

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

As an introduction to RNN/LSTM (stateless) I'm training a model with sequences of 200 days of previous data (X), including things like daily price change, daily volume change, etc and for the labels/Y I have the % price change from current price to that in 4 months. Basically I want to estimate the market direction, not to be 100% accurate. But I'm getting some odd results...

When I then test my model with the training data, I notice the output from the model is a perfect fit when compared to the actual data, it just lags by *exactly* 4 months:

[image]

When I shift the data by 4 months, you can see it's a perfect fit.

[image]

I can obviously understand why the training data would be a very close fit as it has seen it all during training - but why the 4 months lag?

It does the same thing with the validation data (note the area I highlighted with the red box for future reference):

[image]

Time-shifted:

[image]

It's not as close-fitting as the training data, as you'd expect, but still *too* close for my liking - I just don't think it can be this accurate (see the little blip in the red rectangle as an example). I think the model is acting as a naive predictor, I just can't work out how/why it's possibly doing it.

To generate this output from the validation data, I input a sequence of 200 timesteps, but there's nothing in the data sequence that says what the %price change will be in 4 months - it's entirely disconnected, so how is it *so* accurate?  The 4-month lag is obviously another indicator that something's not right here, I don't know how to explain that, but I suspect the two are linked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I realised my error; the way I was using the model to generate the forecast line was naive. For every date in the graph above, I was getting an output from the model, and then apply the forecasted % change to the actual price for that date - that would give predicted price in 4 months' time.

Given the markets usually only move within a margin of 0-3% (plus or minus) over a 4 month period, that would mean my forecasts was always going to closely mirror the current price, just with a 4 month lag.

So at every date the predicted output was being re-based, so the model line would never deviate far from the actual; it'd be the same, but within a margin of 0-3% (plus or minus).

Really, the graph isn't important, and it doesn't reflect the way I'll use the output anyway, so I'm going to ditch trying to get a visual representation, and concentrate on trying to find different metrics that lower the validation loss.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explain the observation based on some general underlying concept:

1. If you don't provide a time-lagged X input dataset (lagged t-k where k is the time steps), then basically you will be feeding the LSTM with like today's closing price to predict the same today's closing price..in the training stage. The model will (over fit) and behave Exactly as the answer is known already (data leakage)
2. If the Y is the predicted percentage change (ie. X * (1 + Y%) = 4 months future price), the present value Yvalue predicted really is just the future discounted by the Y%
   so the predicted value will have 4 months shift

Comment: 1. It's time-lagged training data; where X is  t-k (as multi-variate timesteps) with Y label as the price change from current price to what the price was 40 days into the future.

2. I don't think so; the model never sees what the current price is.

Comment: The reason for the behaviour is given in my answer below. Say my model trains to be accurate within a +/- 3% error range.  Say on 1st Jan 2000 I feed to previous 30 days of data and output says +2.1%, price now is 100 so in 4 months the price is 102.1, so I plot that on 1st May. On 2nd January I repeat that and it says +2%, price now is 101, so for 2nd May I plot 103.2. Repeat over and over and I basically just output an echo of the current price +/- [0-3]%.  No great mystery, just the way I was using it to visualise wasn't very good.